Jumping in ursina python
How to make a code in python ursina engine that makes the player jump higher?
I tried to write:
class level_1_class(Entity):
    def __init__(self,\**kwargs):
        self.player = FirstPersonController()
        super().__init__(parent = self.player)
        self.blocks = []
        self.player.position.z = 10
        self.player.speed = 300
        self.player.scale = 90
        self.jump = 1000

I was expecting that in my map the player that I made will jump high but it didn't work(line number 10)

You can use built-in FirstPersonController and then modify jump_height property:
import ursina
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController

app = ursina.Ursina(fullscreen=False)
player = FirstPersonController()
player.jump_height = 100
for x in range(20):
    for y in range(20):
        ursina.Entity(parent=ursina.scene, model='cube', color='green', position=(x, -10, y), texture='grass', collider='box')

app.run()


